# Is there a way to get a picture out of a Nandroid backup?

Tags: backup, nandroid

I had a picture on my device and did a Nandroid backup and then flashed the device without transferring the picture. Can I get just the picture out? I try exploring the backup but it's just a bunch of files I don't recognize.

Answer (score 1):

You probably search for the contents of your internal SD card (the `Pictures` directory I assume).

Then you need to explore the `data` backup. Inside there should be a `media` directory (and then maybe a `0` directory). This should contain your internal SD card's content of your user. There you can explore all your data.

> Small side note: Not all backup methods save this particular folder. It's generally very big and should be backed up independently. Last I would also recommend an external SD card (if applicable) to save important data on.

Comment: I do have an external SD card, I thought the pictures would automatically be backed up there but I guess not?

Comment: If you have configured your camera app to save all pictures to your external SD then you don't need the backup